# Cannot access file from website with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

So I have information from a text file displayed on a webpage that gets updated every second. Right now is uses Dr*pb*x to host the text file, but I'm trying to move it to my own webserver ran on Windows Server 2008. Unfortunately, when  I do this, it fails to load the file correctly and doesn't display the information.

Here is the code I use to get the information.

```
        function myFunction() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://123.123.123.123/files/my_text_file.txt', //Works if it's a public Dr*pb*x link.
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(text) {
                    $("#myID").text(text);
                    setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
                }
            })
        }
```

The IP, 13.123.123.123 is where the IP to my webserver would be for direct access. An example Dr*pb*x link would be like: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21038723/some_text_file.txt

If I just a Dr*pb*x link then it'll load just fine and display the information, but if I use my webservers link then it won't.

Comment: Is there some issue with spelling out Dropbox?

Comment: Try to use JSONP instead

Comment: what is the error in the browser console?

Comment: @ArunPJohny In regards to that, it says "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.3.205.68/files/CurSong.txt. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: that says it all... it is a cross domain request.... you need to use either CORS(not supported in all browsers) or jsonp to support this

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Got it working using http://anyorigin.com - but why does a Dropbox link work? Shouldn't that cause the same problem?